# C# MVC Unit Testing: Check if View exists by name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, view

I have many controller actions that return a view. Currently we just test whether the ActionResult is not null, but this doesn't actually test whether a valid view will be returned.

I do not want to just check the name, i feel like this is too fragile. What i want to do is grab the view name returned in the ActionResult and somehow check if that view exists/compiles.

Comment: Ask yourself, what would satisfy you as a "valid view"?  Then test for that...

Comment: A valid view is any view in my application that exists, just not sure how to check that.

Comment: Simply `Assert.IsNotNull(viewResult)` should suffice.

Comment: I tested this by putting in a bogus view name, the action result is not null, and has the modern and bogus view name. However obviously wouldn't actually return a view.

Comment: @SomeRandomDeveloper this would be more of an integration test because you would have to have to use the view engine to try and resolve the view

Comment: var viewEngineResult = viewResult.ViewEngineCollection.FindView(controllerContext, viewResult.ViewName, viewResult.MasterName);
Assert.IsNotNull(viewEngineResult);